# Document root (APCHE2)

Tags: apache2, root, localhost

CAn any one tell me how can have multipe localhost directory on my computer.
I already set my localhost as "/home/dee/php" in apache config file setting this

```
Documentroot /home/dee/php
```

Now How can I make more localhost folders other than this?

Should I write?

```
DOCUMENTROOT /home/dee/php and /home/dee/php2
```

or

```
DOCUMENTROOT /home/dee/php 
DOCUMENTROOT /home/dee/php2
```

or else?

both are wrong , and you suggest?

please Guys help me I'm confused badly..

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: There can be only one DocumentRoot for every VirtualHost. What do you want to do?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch is it possible to create multiple virtualhost ? if how?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I'm tring to make one to practice php and otherone for wordpress installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a second virtual host for your wordpress installation save the following as e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpress-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpress-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/wordpress >
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add the line

```
127.0.0.1   wordpress
```

to `/etc/hosts`. Adapt the configuration to your needs, but make sure the name after `ServerName` has an entry in `/etc/hosts`.

Enable this new site using

```
sudo a2ensite wordpress
```

If you didn't save the file as `wordpress.conf` but `somethingelse.conf` use `somethingelse` instead of `wordpress` here.

Then reload the Apache configuration:

```
sudo  service apache2 reload
```

Now you should be able to access the files in `/var/www/wordpress/` using `http://wordpress/`. Use that folder to install WordPress

See [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/name-based.html) for more about virtual hosts.